# Having Problem with Currency format Column Calculation in my dGV in C# Winform Application

Tags: c#

How can I resolve this problem –  I use OleDbDataReader to Read the Price from Database to the TextBox  “Unit Price” with the currency format  but the issues is the Subtotal column calculation Stop working. 
See below image 1  for details. As you can see when I read the Price to the Unit Price TextBox as currency format the Subtotal stop working and the total Qty. see the code where I use the currency format.

```
while (reader.Read()){txtPrice.Text = Convert.ToDouble(reader["Price"]).ToString("C",info);}
```

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJtqk.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUuZh.png)

But if I remove the currency format and use custom format for the textbox “Unit Price” everything work fine but I really want the currency format on the unit Price txtBox. 
See when the format is removed and the custom format is used see code below and  image 2.

```
while (reader.Read()){txtPrice.Text = Convert.ToDouble(reader["Price"]).ToString("#,00.00");}
```

SUBTOTAL CALCULATION CODE

```
           private void Subtolcalculation(){

        for (int i = 0; i < dataGVfrontsale.Rows.Count - 1; i++)

        {
            CultureInfo info;
            info = new CultureInfo("en-NG");double colPrice = double.Parse(dataGVfrontsale.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value.ToString());
            double colQty = double.Parse(dataGVfrontsale.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value.ToString());
            double subtol = colPrice * colQty;
              dataGVfrontsale.Rows[i].Cells[7].Value = subtol;//.ToString("C", info);


        }
```

CODE FOR TOTAL QUANTITY / CURRENCY

```
 private double Total1()   {
        double totl = 0;

        int i = 0;
        for (i = 0; i < dataGVfrontsale.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            totl = totl + Convert.ToDouble(dataGVfrontsale.Rows[i].Cells[5].Value);
        }

        return totl;

    }





       public void calculColumns()
    {
        //Currency Symbol  total on Textbox 
        CultureInfo info;
        info = new CultureInfo("en-NG");


        txtTolQty.Text = Total1().ToString("C", info); //txtGrndTl.Text = Total22().ToString("#,00.00");

        //txtFinalTot.Text = Total22().ToString("C", info);


     }
```

Comment: use `double.Parse(currencyValue, NumberStyles.Currency);` for converting currency to double.

Comment: thank you for your help but please can you show me how i can apply it to my code